# Passing ListView to another Listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have listview in one fragment that displays item from a sqlite database. When I click on one item it opens a menu to allow to open, add to another listview or delete. I want to be able to add it to another listview in another fragment on press. I tried adding it to another listview using bundles but I had no luck. I have a plan of creating another database table to store the added data and display it in a new listview. Would this work? or do any of you guys have another suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can send data from one fragment to another. The best way to do this is by going through the parent activity. Something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MyFragmentListener {
    MyFragment1 frag1;
    MyFragment2 frag2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(0);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        frag1 = (MyFragment1) fm.findFragmentByTag("frag1");
        frag1.setListener(this);
        frag2 = (MyFragment2) fm.findFragmentByTag("frag2");
    }

    // Call this function from frag1 when you want to send the data to frag2
    public void addToFrag2(ListItem item) {
        frag2.addToList(item);
    }
}

// Define whatever methods the fragments want to use to pass data back and forth
public interface MyFragmentListener {
    void addToFrag2(ListItem item);
}
```